# Angular: form submit with dynamic dropdown list

Tags: angularjs

I have a small form and in that form i have a drop down list. List items are generated dynamically.

```
$http({
    url: 'alljobs.php',
    method: "GET",
    params: {
        uid: viewer_id
    }
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.jobss = data.content;
});
```

Below is the code for form submit.

```
 $scope.formprofile33 = function() {
     var allData33 = {
         'msg': $scope.msg,
         'emp_id': viewer_id,
         'job_id': job.job_id,
         'job_title': $scope.jobss.SelectedOption.job_title,
         //    'job':job,
         'user_id': user_id
     }

     $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'send_msg.php',
         data: allData33,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }
     }).success(function(data) {
         if (!data.success) {
             $scope.message = data.errors.message;
         } else {
             $scope.message = '';
             alert('Your message has been sent.');
             $scope.message = '';
         }
     });
 };
```

Here is the form.

```
<form name="formProfile33" method="post" id="formProfile33" role="form" ng-submit="formprofile33()">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-10">                                          
                        <div class="col-xs-12 s_ma">
                            <select id="job" name="job" class="search_color selectors form-control" ng-model="job" required="required" ng-options="item.job_title for item in jobss track by item.job_id"> 
                                <option value=""> Select Job *</option>       
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <textarea name="msg" ng-model="msg" class="form-control textbox1" id="msg" placeholder="Write your message" required="required" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <center>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name="btn-save1" id="btn-save1" required="required"><i class="icon ion-email"></i> Send Message </button>
        </center>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is I am not able to pass dropdown value and id during form submit.

I am getting below error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'job_title' of undefined

How can I submit the form with dropdown id and value?

Comment: have you tried to set data this way: data: JSON.stringify(allData33),

Comment: why this should exists? $scope.jobss.SelectedOption. You do not write anything there so this object is undefined

Comment: As you have ng-model="job" on the select, have you tried to use $scope.job ?

Answer (score 0):

Your example set a job item to the scope field "job" => `ng-model="job"`,
the full selected item is accessible with `$scope.job`.

Try `$scope.job.job_title` or `$scope.job.job_id`

A print out in your html is anytime a good helper: `Full job item: {{job | json}}`

https://plnkr.co/edit/VenFVchI0brGZNC2Q7Fn?p=preview